# jQuery appending HTML tags after a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending HTML code into a div, it's an unordered list. So first I do:

```
$('.placeholder').append('<ul>');
```

This works as expected. Then I do a loop for the list items:

```
$.each(headings, function(index, heading){
    $('.placeholder').append('<li>' + heading + '</li>');
})
```

Then append the closing ul tag

```
$('.placeholder').append('</ul>');
```

The problem is the code comes out like so:

```
<ul></ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

Why is it appending the closing ul tag  at the beginning of the each loop when the code is written so it appends it afterwards?

Comment: appending is NOT like building a string. You are creating a single element. You need to append the lis to the ul that you created.

Comment: `$('.placeholder ul').append('<li>' + heading + '</li>');` and ditch `$('.placeholder').append('</ul>');`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do `.append('</ul>');`. `.append('<ul>');` has already added the full `ul node` to the HTML.

Plus, you need to add your `lis` inside your `ul`, not inside `.placeholder` :

```
$.each(headings, function(index, heading){
    $('.placeholder ul').append('<li>' + heading + '</li>');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Append both the starting *and* closing tag:

```
$('.placeholder').append('<ul></ul>');
```

Then append your `<li>`'s *inside* your `<ul>`:

```
$.each(headings, function(index, heading) {
    $('.placeholder ul').append('<li>' + heading + '</li>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map instead to append them all at once, at the end.

```js
var $ul = $('<ul>');

$ul.append(
  $.map(headings, function(element){
    return '<li>' + element + '</li>';
  })
);

$('.placeholder').append($ul);
```